# DLLImport with dynamic size return

Tags: c#, c++, c, dma

I have a function in a dll to read memory using my kernel drive:

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) PVOID ReadKernelProcessMemory(ULONG Pid, ULONG Address, ULONG Size) {
   checkDriver();
   KERNEL_READ_REQUEST read_Request;
   read_Request.m_aPID = Pid;
   read_Request.m_bAddress = Address;
   read_Request.m_cSize = Size;
   read_Request.m_dResponse = 0;
   DWORD bytes;
   DeviceIoControl(hDriver, IO_READ_REQUEST, &read_Request, sizeof(read_Request),
       &read_Request, sizeof(read_Request), &bytes, 0);
   return (PVOID) read_Request.m_dResponse;
}
```

and I call it from c# using DllImport:

```
[DllImport("Wrapper.dll")] 
public static extern IntPtr ReadKernelProcessMemory(int pid, int address, int size);
```

and that's to transform IntPtr to an object:

```
public T read<T>(int address)
{
    int size = 1;
    if (typeof(T) != typeof(bool))
    {
        size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    }
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(ReadKernelProcessMemory(this.process.Id, address, size), GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T stuff = (T) Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
    handle.Free();
    return stuff;
}
```

but as i'm using IntPtr in a 64-bits architecture it's fixed 8 bits size.
How can I get a return bigger than 8 bits, for exemple I need to read vectors from memory which is 12 bits long?

Comment: If you need to return something that's not a `IntPtr`, why are you returning a `IntPtr` rather than the thing to *need*? You cannot magically transform one thing to another thing. You need to return the *actual thing*.

Comment: Beacuse I will use this function to many objects, such as vectors, strings, ints, floats, structs, etc. so I need a object that than be transform into any thing.

Comment: That sounds wrong. C++ doesn't usually work like that.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's C#. it's returing a PVOID from the Dll, but C# doesn't have a good PVOID conversion, so I trying to find a way to do it.